# Select columns with only NULL values : Hive

Tags: hive, null

I am working on huge data where my table has more than 300 million rows.
The table has 500 columns and some of the columns contains only null values.
How can I get the list of all null columns or columns which have something other than null, any of the above will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return true if column contains not NULLs:

```
select 
max(col1 is not null) col1_not_null,
max(col2 is not null) col2_not_null,
...
max(coln is not null) coln_not_null
from your table;
```

Comment: I will have to write this for all 500 columns, is there any dynamic or short query that does the trick